# In my firefox extension, onUninstalled event doesn't seem to fire

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4

Firefox 4 exposes some events to detect when the user is uninstalling an extension.  I can get `onUninstalling` to fire (when the user clicks to remove an extension), but I can't get anything to happen when `onUninstalled` fires (which should occur after the restart).

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
AddonManager.addAddonListener({
    onUninstalled: function(addon){
        //does not work
        alert("uninstalled!");
    },
    onUninstalling: function(addon){
        //works as expected
        alert("uninstalling!");   
    }
  });
```

I'm ultimately hoping to show a page after the user uninstalls my extension. I'd prefer to do it after onUninstalled if I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `onUninstalled` is called after the extension has been removed - so your extension cannot possibly receive its own uninstall event, it is no longer around to receive it. You can get the notification about other add-ons being uninstalled however, that's the point of this event. Looking at the source code, there appears to be an additional catch - this notification is only sent for add-ons that don't require a restart. This makes sense given that a restart can change the situation radically because external applications added or removed add-ons in the extensions directory. So Firefox doesn't even attempt to communicate changes that happened while it wasn't running, any listeners should simply re-read the list of add-ons on each browser start.

To sum up, as a "classic" extension you have to go with `onUninstalling` even though this event doesn't guarantee that the extension will be uninstalled (the user can still revert his choice). Bootstrapped extensions (the ones that don't require a restart, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions) have it easier, method `uninstall()` in their bootstrap.js will be called even if the extension is disabled. However, turning your extension into a bootstrapped one isn't always easy, there is a number of catches attached to that: http://adblockplus.org/blog/how-many-hacks-does-it-take-to-make-your-extension-install-without-a-restart

Comment: Great explanation!  Thanks for the thoughtful reply.